# Why was the flag declined, even though the answer was deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, declined-flags

I had flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19668131/2024761) as *not an answer*. The flag was declined by a moderator stating this reason

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

So I thought that I might have wrongly flagged the answer, and thus moved on. But later today, I just happened to stumble upon that answer again and I see that it was deleted after all by a moderator. Why was my flag declined in that case? Is there something which I'm missing about the flags and moderator deletion?

**Note** - Since the answer under discussion was deleted by a moderator already, it can be seen only by users with *10k+* reputation on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were three NAA flags on the post at the time yours was declined by the first moderator. Past that, five more appeared before it was deleted by a second moderator.

So the first moderator disagreed that it was not an answer, and the second moderator agreed. A simple difference in opinions, because the answer is a bit of an edge-case.

Comment: Just a small doubt. I now know that it was a difference in opinions, but are there any ground rules/guidelines for the moderators based on which they take such calls, regarding deletion of answers, accepting certain edge-case flags, etc?

Comment: I had such senarios some times too. Should this not been treated in some way to avoid bad flag weight?

Comment: @rekire There is no flag weight anymore. A declined flag does not affect your ability to flag in the future, at all. Unless you cast a lot of them and get suspended, but that's a different story (and very manual).

Comment: @animuson good to know I mixed that up.

Comment: So genuinely flagged posts, which get declined because of edge-case scenarios would not my account suspended or post a flag-ban on me right?!

Comment: @R.J Nope. There is no flag ban, and it would take some serious flag trolling to get suspended for it.

Comment: Yup; what @animuson said! (I was the first mod, who declined.)